# Titanium mobile

Tags: mobile, titanium

I have just briefly looked at this as a possible technology to use for a mobile app I have ini mind but can any one tell me do I need to be paying a support subscription to use the GWT-RPC jar.  I briefly looked at an RPC tutorial and this is the impression I get?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop and distribute Titanium for free. You don't need to pay or to subscribe for anything.

Only if you want support or using special features (ACS Cloud Services, Modules) you'll need to pay.